# Regular Language Operation

Tags: automata, regular-language

I need to show that the given regular language is closed under the following operation.

For example:
`AllSuffixes(L) = {v : uv in L for some u in (0+1)* }`

I do not have any idea about this question. I only know that regular languages are closed under `+` , `.` and `*` operations.

Do you have any idea(a solution way or a clue)?

Comment: Do you know about non-deterministic finite state automata (NFAs)?

Comment: Yes, I know DFA, NFA and Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to start with a DFA that recognizes $L$ and has no inaccessible states. Now add empty transitions from the initial state to each other state and show that the resulting NFA does what you want.

You can also approach it via regular grammars. Start with a regular grammar for $L$. If $S$ is the initial symbol, add a production $S\to X$ for each accessible non-terminal symbol $X$ other than $S$. This is basically exactly the same idea. In both cases the idea is to let the machine/grammar start at any point that the original machine/grammar could have reached from the initial state/symbol.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the first approach? I am new at this topic, It can be more clear for me.

Comment: @g2d: Just draw an arrow from the initial state to each of the other states, and label it with $\epsilon$ or $\lambda$, whichever is your symbol for the empty word.

Comment: I did it but I did not understand how it does it.

Comment: @g2d: An NFA accepts a word if there is at least one path governed by that word that ends in an acceptor state. Those $\epsilon$ transitions that you added in effect allow the automaton to start at any state. Suppose that the original DFA $M$ accepts $011$ and has a transition $q_0\overset{0}\longrightarrow q_1$, where $q_0$ is the initial state. You want your NFA to accept $11$, since it’s a suffix, and it does: it can begin with an $\epsilon$ transition from $q_0$ to $q_1$, and from there it operates just like $M$, so it ends up in the same accepting state as $M$ did with the input $011$.

Comment: Okay, it is clear now. Thank you!

Comment: @g2d: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to first prove a slightly easier exercise, namely that the language
$$
  \text{AllPrefixes}(L) = \{v \mid vu \in L \text{ for some $u \in \{0,1\}^*$} \}
$$
is regular. If you succeed to do so, then you could use the fact that regular languages are closed under *reversal*. If $u = a_1 \dotsm a_n$ is a word, its reversal is the word $\tilde{u} = a_n \dotsm a_1$, and the reversal of a language $L$ is the language $\tilde{L} = \{\tilde{u} \mid u \in L \}$. The next step would be to verify that the language
AllSuffixes(L) is the reversal of $\text{AllPrefixes}(\tilde{L})$.